# How to Get Letters of Recommendation after Graduating in 2005

Tags: recommendation-letter

It has been 16 years since I graduated from college. Any suggestions in how to obtain letters of recommendations if professors may no longer work at the university?

Comment: Letters for what? Masters? PhD? Something else?

Comment: There is no rule that a letter of recommendation must be written by a professor. You should get letters from someone who knows you from the last few years and can attest to your abilities and potential to succeed in whatever program you’re applying to.

Comment: Probable duplicates: [Out of school for ten years and letters of recommendation for PhD programs](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/95392/out-of-school-for-ten-years-and-letters-of-recommendation-for-phd-programs), [Ask for a letter of recommendation after 11-year hiatus?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/149088/ask-for-a-letter-of-recommendation-after-11-year-hiatus)

Comment: You may get the reference letter from you current supervisor and colleagues

Comment: On top of the questions mentioned by @cag51 there's also [Who writes the recommendation letters for returning student PhD applicants after a big hiatus?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/108288/17254)